# How to find a sequence $\{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$based on the following assumption?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How to find a sequence $\{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ such that

$b_n\gt 0$ for all $n\ge 1$ and

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}b_n=0$ and

the series $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n+1}b_n$ is divergent.

For alternating series, the sequence converges if and only if $b_n\to 0$ based on the assumption that $b_n\gt 0$ for all $n\ge 1$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}b_n=0$ and the **series is decreasing**. So I think we have to find a nondecreasing sequence. But how do you find a nondecreasing function that has $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}b_n=0$?

Comment: Interleave the "bad" sequence $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,\dots$ with the good sequence $1,1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,\dots$.

Comment: But how do you express such?

Comment: The "$b_n$ decreasing to zero" condition is sufficient but not necessary for convergence of an alternating series. See example in this answer (also by @AndréNicolas): http://math.stackexchange.com/a/288650/215011

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Interleave the "bad" sequence $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,\dots$ with the good sequence $1,1/2,1/4,1/8,1/16,\dots$.

If a formula is desired, if $n=2k-1$ we let $b_n=\frac{1}{k}$, and if $n=2k$ we let $b_n=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$.